# Make some keys of the keyboard invisible

Tags: android, keyboard

It is convenient to customize the keyboard available for users.

Depending on the position of the cursor, I want to show two different keyboards, similar to the ones shown in the pictures.

[image: full keyboard]

[image: constraint keyboard]

In the second keyboard some keys are omitted to prevent wrong input. How can it be achieved, that the displayed keys are at the same positions as they are on the full keyboard, ie the omitted keys are supposed to be "invisible" but not "gone". Unfortunately, I cannot find corresponding xml-attributes for the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're saying that the 'up arrow' key is 'moving' over to the left side because you've got rid of the 'EE' key?

I *think* that you're just after `android:horizontalGap` that can be applied to each `Keyboard.Key`. I would create two layouts. The first is the top keyboard, and the second is essentially a tweaked version of the first, using the aforementioned `android:horizontalGap` to add padding. So when the event occurs that causes the switch, the `Keyboard` changes to the correct layout.

Answer (score 0):

I hava a simple solution.
Set you target key x or y property into a incorrect value.This key will be invalidated status .Code like that

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    //keyboard.keys[index].x = -999
    keyboard.keys[index].y = -999
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    //do something
}
```